# where best to define enumerations java?

Tags: java, enums

Is there a "best practice" for the place at which an enum should be defined in java?

One option is to have a separate .java file for each enum, and any class that uses that enum can include it.

example:

Direction.java:

```
public enum Direction {
    INPUT, OUTPUT, UNKNOWN
}
```

Type.java

```
public enum Type{
    DATA, VALID, READY, UNKNOWN
}
```

Another option is to have one big file with all the enums in my application, and if a class uses any of the enums, it will have to include that big file.

example:

MyEnums.java

```
public class MyEnums{
    public enum Direction {
        INPUT, OUTPUT, UNKNOWN
    }

    public enum Type{
        DATA, VALID, READY, UNKNOWN
    }
}
```

Which of the two options is better, both in terms of performance and code portability/extensibility? or is it a matter of choice and there is no one better option? What is the best way to define enumerations in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you're not planning to expose the usage of the enum, for e.g. `Direction` then you could do it right in the class which is using it. I mean that you could make it private, such as:

## 1 As inner type (direct usage)

```
public class Foo {

    private Direction directionType = Direction.UNKNOWN;

    // some code

    private enum Direction {
        INPUT, OUTPUT, UNKNOWN
    }
}
```

## 2 As an external type

Write enums w/ logic (if there is some) in the separate `*.java` files. This is absolutely fine approach. Example below is the classical one from the [Oracle Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }

    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java Planet <earth_weight>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    double earthWeight = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double mass = earthWeight/EARTH.surfaceGravity();
    for (Planet p : Planet.values())
       System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                         p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
}
```

}

## Summary

It really depends on the context and the architecture decision. Basically grouping enums in the one `java` file is not the best solution especially when your application begins 'to grow'. The code will be hard to read for other developers that will work on it. I suggest to use the approach **#1** or **#2**

Answer (score 0):

The general practice that I have seen is to have a package for all the enums and each enum is in its own java file with all the associated methods for that enum. If all you're going to have is just a bunch of enums with no methods operating on the contents of the enum, I guess it then just boils down to a matter of choice.

Imagine the common scenario where each enum has several methods associated with the constants it holds. You can see that having several enums in a single class can very easily make the code clunky. But on the other hand, if you are just going to have a collection of enums, it might even be desirable to put them all together in one place for the sake of brevity.

There would be no difference as far as performance and portability are concerned - you just need to think whether the code becomes clunky or not.

Answer (score 0):

Same as for any other class or interface.

The fact that it's an enumeration doesn't change the basic nature of the question.